# find the maximum value of sum of subarray modulo M

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming

The question is  - You are given an array of size N and another integer M. Your target is to find the maximum value of sum of subarray modulo M.

```
If array is {3 3 9 9 5} and M is {7}
```

Possible subarrays are

```
{3},{3},{9}.{9}.{5}
{3,3},{3,9},{9,9},{9,5}
{3,3,9},{3,9,9},{9,9,5}
{3,3,9,9},{3,9,9,5},{3,3,9,9,5}
```

out of which max possible sum taking modulo 7 will be 6. Subarray {3,3} has the maximum sum.

I came across the solution, but unable to understand the logic

```
static void solve(long M, long[] array){
    TreeSet<Long> sumSet = new TreeSet<Long>();
    long best = 0;
    long sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

        sum = (sum + array[i]) % M;
        Long up = sumSet.higher(sum);
        if(up == null){
            best = Math.max(best,sum);
        } else {
            best = Math.max(best, M - up + sum);
        }
        sumSet.add(sum);
    }

    System.out.println(best);
}
```

What does the line mean

```
 best = Math.max(best, M - up + sum);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modular arithmetic, adding the divisor to the result doesn't make a difference. For example, `-1 (mod N)` is same as `N-1`.
In your algorithm, `M - up + sum` is subtracting `up` from `sum` and since it will always be negative, adds `M` to make the result positive.

What the algorithm is doing?

- Iterate over the array and maintain a running sum using the variable `sum`
- Keep storing the running `sum` into a `TreeSet`. The idea is to be able to extract a sum in `O(log N)`. `sum - (any number from sumSet)` is the sum of a sub-array. If the result is negative, adding up `M` gives a positive sum of the sub-array.
- Extract the least integer greater than `sum` from `sumSet`. Why? The maximum sum possible is the least negative. The maximum modulo sum possible is `M - 1`. It is obtained when `sum - up` is equal to `-1`.
- If there is no such previous sum, compare the present `sum` with the `best`.
- Else, compare `sum - up + M` with `best`.

Complexity: `O(n log n)`

Comment: nice explanation ..was thinking of geting in O(n) but coz of treeset its O(nlogn). But its better than generating all subsets and checking which will cause O(n2)